# How do I return all results that don't contain a certain value in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have some data in my mongodb database that looks similar to this:

```
[
  {
    username: 'will',
    post: 'some random post',
    user_id: '12345',
    _id: 0
  },
  {
    username: 'jogno',
    post: 'some random post',
    user_id: '23412',
    _id: 1
  },
  {
    username: 'aflack',
    post: 'some random post',
    user_id: '24332',
    _id: 2
  }
]
```

If my user_id is 12345, I want my query to return the other 2 posts where the user_id does NOT equal 12345. However when I use the query below it just returns all 3 posts, am I missing something or is there a different and better way to do this? Thanks

```
Post.find(
  { user_id: { $not: 12345 } }
)
```

SOLUTION:
I had to use $ne instead of $not

Answer (score 0):

In your database, the user_id is a string, but in your query you are selecting a number.

Also, you should be using $ne for this.

Try $ne: "12345"

Comment: Thanks, it turns our I needed to use $ne instead of $not

Comment: Yeah, my first answer had $not thinking it was a datatype issue, and then I too realized that the operator was the issue.